# Are stack based arrays possible in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, stack

Let's say, hypothetically (read: I don't think I actually need this, but I am curious as the idea popped into my head), one wanted an array of memory set aside locally on the stack, not on the heap. For instance, something like this:

```
private void someFunction()
{
    int[20] stackArray; //C style; I know the size and it's set in stone
}
```

I'm guessing the answer is no. All I've been able to find is heap based arrays. If someone were to need this, would there be any workarounds? Is there any way to set aside a certain amount of sequential memory in a "value type" way? Or are structs with named parameters the only way (like the way the [Matrix struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix_members.aspx) in XNA has 16 named parameters (M11-M44))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is [`stackalloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4.aspx); unfortunately, you can only use this in unsafe code, which means it won't run in a limited permissions context.

You could also create a struct with the necessary number of variables in it for each element type, but you would need a new type for each size of 'array' you wanted to use

Comment: Hm, what about a primitive LinkedList? On your struct set previous / next struct of same type...you don't get ICollection semantics, but it could be enough for IEnumerable...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, are struct based LinkedLists possible? And do you have an idea why there isn't a Safe stack based array option in .NET?

Comment: @Frank: You can't do this - when I try to compile a recursive struct, I get a 'CS0523: Struct member <member info> causes a cycle in the struct layout'

Comment: @thecoop What if you make your node nullable?

Comment: `Nullable<T>` is still a struct, so it wont work. Think about it - when you declare a recursive struct, you're basically asking the CLR to allocate space for an infinite list of structs.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't know why a stack based array isn't possible in safe code though. I can't see how an array is much different than a struct or why this isn't possible...but that's another matter altogether I guess

Comment: Thanks for checking out...it does make sense as you explain it. Clever compiler!

Comment: Stack based arrays would be unsafe to use, because a reference to the array might outlive the array (which will get destroyed as soon as the function quits). A new array type with different behavior would be needed for such an array.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of to a stack-based array would be a manually-nested structure; for an array of size N^M, the code size would be O(MN) and the access time O(M); one could scale M and N as convenient (e.g. one could handle a 4096-element array as six-deep nested 4-element structures, four-deep nested 8-element structures or three-deep nested 16-element structures, two-deep nested 64-element structures, etc.)  If one wanted to do three-deep nesting of 16-element arrays (probably the most practical trade-off) one would define a 16-element structure with fields f0 through f15, and an access method using switch/case to select an element.  One could then define a 16-element structure of those, a 16-element structure of those, etc.

In general, using a standard Array is apt to be better than using value-type structures to mimic arrays, but there are times when having an array-ish thing as a value type would be advantageous.  The advantages of value type arrays would tend to be limited in .net, however, by some limitations in its handling of manipulating value types by reference.  While it would be nice if one could simply access element 0x123 from an array described as above by writing "MyArrayishThing[1][2][3]", that would be inefficient for reading and ineffective for writing (since the subexpression MyArrayishThing[1] would make a copy of structures holding 256 elements of the array).  Instead, what's necessary is to pass MyArrayishThing[1] by reference to a routine that can access element 2 of that and pass it by reference to a routine to access element 3 of that.  It's possible to do that efficiently, but the code ends up looking rather nasty.